# Inserted value in database using PreparedStatement obj

Tags: java, database

I have a java code and I want to insert data in to my database table(users) through **PreparedStatement object** but it gives me some error.
how can I resolve it?

my code is :

```
else
            {
                m.msgbox("work");
                m.pst1=m.con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?)");

                m.msgbox(txtuser.getText());
                m.msgbox(m.login);
                m.msgbox(txtpass.getText());

                m.pst1.setString(1,txtuser.getText());
                m.pst1.setString(2,m.login);
                m.pst1.setString(3,txtpass.getText());

                m.pst1.executeUpdate();

                m.msgbox("Value updated Successfully...");
                m.pst1.close();

            }
```

here **m.login** is any String value and **m.msgbox()** is my function for showing message.

stack trace is :

```
H:\Workspace\Mining Inventory\Project\src>java mdiform
java.sql.SQLException: General error
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6985)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3148)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedState
ment.java:215)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPrepare
dStatement.java:137)
        at ChangePass.actionPerformed(ChangePass.java:200)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
18)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
a:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259
)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
istener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
```

Comment: Show the error, `some error` doesn't help us much:-)

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace you have when doing executeUpdate()?

Comment: Plus, this code is scary. Your `m` object handles the message box **and** the connection to the database as well?

Comment: we can't help you unless you tell what is the error

Comment: i have updated my question please refer again.

Comment: yes the object m handles all. I use it in many more class it is working but here it is not.

Comment: What columns does your users table have? If it's more than three you'll need to specify the exact columns you want to send those values to in the SQL.